# How can you programmatically create a NuGet package in .NET Standard with NuGet V3?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I have written an application which takes a Swagger definition as an input and outputs a .NET Standard proxy as a DLL.

We have an older application that uses NuGet.Core to package up a DLL into a NuGet package and then publish it. This code is not compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 because of a dependency on Microsoft.Web.Xdt.

I've had a look through the documentation for the NuGet V3 package but I can't find any examples of how to generate packages programmatically.

Comment: You cannot use `dotnet pack` on this new application?

Comment: I guess that the application could save the DLL to a filesystem and then attempt to run a shell command to call dotnet pack on it. However this would be dependent on the environment and would be less elegant then just creating the NuGet package in-memory and then saving it or publishing it. It was possible to do this with NuGet.Core so I'm just trying to figure out how to do the same thing in .NET Standard.